# Drupal Views error

Tags: php, pdo, drupal-7, view, drupal-modules

I continue to receive this error with Drupal's views module ever time I try creating a new view, any advice would help, thank you!

PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'human_name' in 'field list': INSERT INTO {views_view} (name, description, tag, base_table, human_name, core) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2, :db_insert_placeholder_3, :db_insert_placeholder_4, :db_insert_placeholder_5); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => upcoming_seminars [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => default [:db_insert_placeholder_3] => node [:db_insert_placeholder_4] => Upcoming Seminars [:db_insert_placeholder_5] => 7 ) in views_db_object->save_row() (line 2224 of C:\xampp\vhosts\csdrupal\sites\all\modules\views\includes\view.inc).

Comment: please show your code for better answers.

Comment: We don't really need the code, since views uses a human readable name for views and that is the column it uses to store that value in. The error itself shows enough as well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your views table has gotton corrupted. Backup all your views (export) and uninstall, then reinstall views. (Devel module has a reinstall option)

OR

In a different Drupal install check the views table and check what settings the `human_name` column is using, then add in your active Drupal install that column.

OR

Check the views module and find the install file to see what tables are created, locate the human_name column and add it to your table.

===

Took the time to look it up for you.

In the table `views_view` create a new column with the values:

- Name = 'human_name'
- VARCHAR
- 255
- ALLOW NULL
- Default = ''
- Comment = 'A human readable name used to be displayed in the admin interface'
- Insert it between the columns `base_table` and `core`